# Jquery Class Selector Not Working With Dynamic Class Selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, listener

I have a bootstrap form group as defined using the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">                
   <label class="control-label" for="input-1">Qty</label>            
      <select name="quantity[]" id="input-1" data-qtyindex="0" class="form-control input-qty">
         <option value="25">25</option>
         <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then dynamically I am adding another form group below this. This new form group has a button group and looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">                
   <label class="control-label" for="input-2">Qty</label>            
   <div class="input-group">
      <select name="quantity[]" id="input-2" data-qtyindex="1" class="form-control input-qty">
         <option value="25">25</option>
         <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-qty">Delete</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to setup a listener to the button in the dynamically loaded form group. So I have some jQuery that looks like this:

```
$('.form-group').on('click','.btn-remove-qty',function(){
    alert("delete");
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
});
```

However that listener never fires. Now before anyone says I should attach it to body or document. Yes that does work, but I want to know why this setup does not work. The .form-group class exists on page load so why can't I bind it to that class and then select all .btn-remove-qty classes inside of it that are added dynamically?

Comment: Try like $('.form-group button.btn-remove-qty').on('click, function () {

Comment: No that did not work

Comment: what is the error you are getting !

Comment: No error. The function just never fires.

Comment: check this fiddle - both are working here https://jsfiddle.net/du4oL4b1/ i feel some other issue

Comment: @Venkatraman, the second form-group is dynamically added

Comment: updated my fiddle to add dynamically form-group and still its working - https://jsfiddle.net/du4oL4b1/1/ @user3167249, please use this fiddle and let us know issue

Comment: Try adding a console.log('event firing'); to the body of your event listener. If you don't see anything in your browser console then it is indeed never or more likely, firing too early(before the document is ready). Have you tried waiting for the window.load event before executing that code?

Comment: try to put your js code just before the body end tag and try like $(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

Comment: You fiddle's have the class .btn-remove-qty at load time. Mine does not. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r14chqv7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [`jQuery .on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()

In your case, the event was not attached to the dynamically added `.form-group` because it doesn't exist when `.on()` is called

You should replace your `.form-group` selector to a static element.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhwojh02/2/). In there I added a `#wrapper div`  and used as the selector.

Comment: So you are saying that jquery basically loops through all elements with the class .form-group at runtime assigning a listener to each one and since my dynamically added .form-group was not there it does not get a listener? If so this makes sense. I was under the impression the listener was assigned to all elements with the .form-group class regardless of when they were loaded just as so long that there was infact one there at runtime.